# Angular module created twice using forChild

Tags: angular, angular11

I have a module, LoginModule, that needs some configuration provided to it, so it provides forRoot.
I use this forRoot() in my AppModule.
Now I have another module, Module2, that itself is imported by AppModule. I need a component from LoginModule in Module2, so Module2 needs to import LoginModule. But how should it do this?

It seems no matter what I do, the LoginModule constructor will be called twice, if Module2 imports LoginModule: Once by forRoot() in the AppModule, and once for the import in Module2.
I have tried to use a forChild-pattern for the import in Module2, but that does not change anything.
Since I want to run some initialization code when the LoginModule gets created, I have setup the solution shown below to detect if the LoginModule is the root one, or not.

I was under the impression that there should not be a second LoginModule at all when using something like forChild. Was I wrong about that? Or am I making a mistake that causes the second LoginModule to exist when it should not?

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
// some things are declared
    ],
    imports: [
// various imports
    ],
    exports: [
// some exported components exist
    ]
})
export class LoginModule {
// forRoot is used to inject a configuration into the module
// LoginModule.forRoot() is used in the AppModule of my app.
    static forRoot(config: UserSystemConfig): ModuleWithProviders<LoginModule> {
        return {
            ngModule: LoginModule,
            providers: [
                LoginService,
                LoginAuthGuard, 
                {
                    provide: libConf, // an injection token
                    useValue: config
                },
                {
                    provide: mKey, // an injection token
                    useValue: true
                }
            ],
        }
    }
// forChild skips providing anything but the key that I use to know if this is the root instance.
    static forChild(): ModuleWithProviders<LoginModule> {
        return {
            ngModule: LoginModule,
            providers: [{
                provide: mKey,
                useValue: false
            }]
        }
    }

    constructor(@Inject(mKey) isRoot: boolean) {
        if (isRoot) {
// Run initialization for the module only in root module.
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forRoot()` and `forChild()` helps you manage your services. It has nothing to do with whether modules' code is executed or not. It will be executed every-time you use it. It just wouldn't make sense if it is not executed.

When you use `forRoot()` and if module is lazy loaded (with its own Injector), its providers would be the same instance of providers in root Injector. Otherwise module would instantiate its own instances of providers.